# mat-form-field in Angular is invisible

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend

I use the following code for an input field to pick a single date.

The problem is, the input field doesn't get show on the website but it's clickable, but the date-icon doesn't exists. I tried to put the background image off but it doesn't work.

Do you have any advice for me?

-The mat-styles are configured for my project.

Html:

```
<div class="frame">
  <div class="title">
    <label>Analyse</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="radioGroup">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox" sm-radio-bind="">
          <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
          <label>Case 1</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="ui radio checkbox" sm-radio-bind="">
          <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
          <label>Case 2</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="ui radio checkbox" sm-radio-bind="">
          <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
          <label>Case 3</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label></mat-label>
          <input placeholder="InputTicker">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="dateInput">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" 
            placeholder="Date">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker">
          </mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #datePicker color="primary"></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">Analyse</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="backbutton">
      <a routerLink="/"><button class="button">Back</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usecase1',
  templateUrl: './usecase1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usecase1.component.css']
})

export class Usecase1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }    
}
```

CSS:

```
.subtitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: pre;
  text-shadow: 11px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 90px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
}
.frame {
  width: auto;
  height: 1056px;
  background-image: url('../../assets/Frontend_Background.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;    
}
.button{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:0.1em solid #000000;
  border-radius:0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:300;
  color:#000000;
  text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align:center;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-size: 25px;    
}
.button:hover{
  text-shadow: 0 0 2em rgba(255,255,255,1);
  color: white;
  border-color: #0077FF;
  background-color: #0077FF;
}
.backbutton{
  margin-right: 95%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 24%;
  justify-content: right;
}
.radioGroup{
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  }
.container{
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-right: 45%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.content{
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 81%;
}
.dateInput{
  color: black;
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router, RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Usecase1Component } from './usecase1/usecase1.component';
import { MainmenuComponent } from './mainmenu/mainmenu.component';
import { Usecase1resultComponent } from './usecase1/usecase1result/usecase1result.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import { MatDatepickerModule} from "@angular/material/datepicker";
import { MatNativeDateModule} from "@angular/material/core";
import { MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
    
const myRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'usecase1', component: Usecase1Component},
  {path: '', component: MainmenuComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Usecase1Component,
    MainmenuComponent,
    Usecase1resultComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Actual output:

[image]

Comment: Looks like there's no material styles confogured in your project.
Try a sulution from the accepted answer of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70043733/dialog-box-appear-in-bottom-of-page-in-angular/70045380#70045380

Comment: I did that before i started to code my page. I did it again to check if I missed something but it doesn't work. I tried the example from the documentation and it also doesn't work. There is just a little pink circle i can't interact with.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: @Stoobish Its my first one. I hope i did everything right: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkbfyz?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @cowboy192, the stackblitz example doesn't work. It prints "Can't find packages: ...". pls, fix it